Mongo Jdbc connection solr
i am trying to connect to mongo using mongo-jdbc driver but connection fails for solr dataimport handler. Below is the error
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 59 (CommandNotFound): 'no such command: 'sqlGetResultSchema'' on server localhost:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "no such command: 'sqlGetResultSchema'", "code": 59, "codeName": "CommandNotFound"}
The following are the drivers I used:
bson-5.2.0.jar, mongodb-driver-sync-5.2.0.jar, mongodb-driver-core-5.2.0.jar, mongodb-jdbc-2.2.0.jar,solr-dataimporthandler-8.5.0.jar
java version: 18
solr version: 8.11.4
I want the connection to be successful but shows connection failed
